# Second media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries, media

The media query for the phone isn't working. I've looked at other posts and have found no solution.

As said above the problem is pretty plain. The media query for the laptop works, but for the phone does not seem to get recognized. 
Website:
www,beesandthebirds.com

```
/*Media queries*/

/*Phone*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {
    #logo{
        background-size: 76%;
        height:60%;
    }
    #text{
        top:49%;
    }
    #text >h1{
        font-size: 4.5em;
    }
    #space{
        bottom: -47px;
    }
    .x8{
        top:625px;
    }
    .x9{
        top:725px;
    }
    .x10{
        top:825px;
    }
}

/*Laptop*/

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width: 1367px) {
    #logo{
        background-size: 21%;
        height:60%;
    }

    #text{
        top:49%;

    }
    #text >h1{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    #space{
        bottom: -47px;
    }


}
```

Comment: Notorious_Creed, try to change `max-width: 415px` to `min-width: 415px`

Comment: I tried and also 0. Als tried to remove the other media query.

I just recently added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

and now it works. 

Thanks anyway

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it tomorrow. It's better for SO to have an answered question than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently added  "meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"" and now it works.

Comment: Oh myyyy! I've been looking for a solution for like 3 hours! thanks a lot